# Faceoff: the ASP.NET MVC3 declarative, format stringstyle routing and node's imperitive routing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, node.js

Here's an example node routing config:

```
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
```

Its a mapping of URLs and request handlers.  Simple, utilitarian, but what about the powerful format string syntax of MVC 3?

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MediaRoute",               // Route name
  "{mediaTopic}/{mediaType}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Media", action = "DisplayMediaItemById" },
  new { mediaType = "Article|Insight|Infographic" }
```

It allows for regexes in the {} variable names like mediaType, used in the route and defining its regex.

I'm sure adding regexes to node routing in some way will solve the disconnect.  Maybe if someone made the MVC->node transition they will have an answer. Have I missed any great node routing features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to turn regexp on your route then look [expressjs guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) for the answer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  This question is a little broader though, I'm interested in knowing the differences and similarities between node/expressJS routing and MVC 3 routing.

Comment: I don know how does MVC 3 work. But i can explain how express do: after request came express drop it in queue of middlewares: first convert it to object and call next() to pass it to the next middleware then it comes to logger, cookie/session parser, MVC-router (for example) or app.router(express built-in router), then static router, then if all middlewares pass control with next() and no response haven't sent yet it goes to last middleware by one which is an not found error middleware. The last is internal error middleware.

Comment: Middlewares it's simple callbacks which could do this: send response, add/update request data and go next() or produce error next(new Error()); Yeah. So easy ))